# Как правильно сформулировать: область видимости или область действия?

Tags: java, c#, c

У меня есть два вопроса, казалось бы и не принципиальных, а скорее уточняющих, мнение по поводу которых хотелось бы услышать от специалистов:

1. Судя по тому, что Википедия содержит упоминание только области видимости, то похоже, что именно эта формулировка является общепринятым на текущий момент переводом значения scope, хотя как мне кажется, совсем недавно более используемым термином была все-таки область действия. Что все-таки ближе к правильному переводу, или никакой разницы здесь нет?
2. Часто при описании области действия (видимости) переменных экземпляра и класса, ограничиваются только тем, что указывают что областью действия переменной экземпляра является весь объект. Этим подчеркивается их отличие от локальных переменных. Однако, как известно, переменные объекта и класса можно использовать и из других объектов (с учетом модификаторов доступа, конечно). Правильно ли будет сказать, что областью действия (видимости) переменной экземпляра (например public) является вся программа. Или все-таки это понятие рассматривается на уровне объекта/класса?

Answer (score 2):

Само по себе понятие scope — это «область». По крайней мере, так переводит Microsoft [в своём официальном словаре](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=scope&langID=ru-ru).

Сравнивая [документ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/scope-and-visibility) с его [переводом](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-language/scope-and-visibility):

- Scope and Visibility = Область и видимость
- File scope = Область видимости файла
- Block scope = Область действия блока

---

Нет, неправильно. Смотрите. Есть процесс (лексической) привязки имён, при котором идентификатору ставится в соответствие объект. То, что имя находится в области (видимости) означает, что это имя, будучи упомянутым, ссылается на объект. Если у вас в классе есть (открытое) поле/свойство `X`, вне класса вы *не можете* ссылаться по имени `X` на это поле.

Вы можете ссылаться на него через имя объекта и точку, это да. Но после имени объекта и точки разрешение имён идёт в области объекта, а не во внешней области.

Пример:

```
class C
{
    public int X; // (1)
    // здесь внутри имя X ссылается на поле (1)
}

int X = 13; // (2)
C c = new C();
X = 100; // в этой области X ссылается на переменную (2)
c. // дальше поиск производится в области объекта C
  X = 200; // Х ссылается на поле (1) объекта c.
```

Comment: Еще раз соглашусь (см. ответ rdorn), но сомнения мои возникли когда стал копать глубже и полез в Википедию. А там, опять-таки см. переписку с rdorn... В общем, у такой казалось бы строгой науки как программирование, возникают неоднозначные толкования, даже когда речь идет о фундаментальных основах...

Comment: @vitaliy4us: В каждом языке понятия свои и немного друг от друга отличаются. Если вы хотите первоисточник, лучше всего читать официальную спецификацию языка, вот там-то уж все понятия определены максимально строго.

Comment: Приникнув к истокам, приходим все-таки к мнению о том, что когда речь идет об области видимости (все-таки видимости?!) переменной, то вопрос об этом решается на уровне объекта:  Instance and class variables and methods have class scope; they can be used outside the class and its subclasses only by prefixing them with an instance of the class or (for class variables and methods) with the class name. Хотя опять таки как-то не совсем категорично и приходится толковать ...

Comment: @vitaliy4us: А вы посмотрите в точности, что такое class scope. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp

Comment: Но опять же - это class scope, а меня же интересует вопрос так как он поставлен в сертификационном экзамене Java:  Define the scope of variables.

Comment: @vitaliy4us: Ну для этого нужно смотреть спецификацию Java, по идее

Answer (score 2):

1. scope - контекстно зависимый термин, поэтому правильность перевода зависит от контекста.
2. Область видимости и область действия - разные понятия.
3. К членам экземпляра класса не возможно обратиться без самого экземпляра, поэтому область действия и видимости членов экземпляра класса - ограничена экземпляром класса. С членами класса (статическими) тоже самое. Область видимости класса(не экземпляра) ограничена пространством имен, в котором он определен. Область действия к классу в общем смысле не применима. Область действия экземпляра так легко определить не получится, она будет зависеть от исполняемого кода. Область видимости к экземпляру в общем смысле не применима.

Comment: Следовательно, область видимости можно рассматривать только на уровне объекта? В принципе, согласен. Но с другой стороны, та же Википедия дает и такие определения:В объектно-ориентированном программировании каждый объект содержит три специфические области видимости:

Закрытая (англ. private) — переменную можно использовать только в реализации объекта;
Общедоступная (англ. public) — переменную можно использовать при использовании и инициализации объекта;
Защищённая (англ. protected) — переменную можно использовать только в реализации объекта или его потомка. Толкование не совсем однозначное

Comment: @vitaliy4us в вики пишут такие же пользователи =) слышали бы вы слова одного из моих преподавателей по полупроводниковой технике по поводу пишущих на вики. и самое страшное, что я с ним согласен. но отслеживать и исправлять все ошибки в вики не хватит ни сил ни времени =(

Comment: @vitaliy4us читайте лучше в оригинале такие моменты, переводы это вечная беда, особенно когда нет взаимно однозначного соответствия терминов в языках оригинала и перевода. public/protected/internal/private - это уровень доступа, или ограничения доступа, но ни как не области видимости.

Comment: К сожалению, с прочтения оригинала, мои сомнения и возникли: MAX_LENGTH is a class variable because it has the static keyword in its declaration. MAX_LENGTH goes into scope on line 2 where it is declared. It stays in scope until the program ends. Как мне кажется, здесь вообще круглое смешано с мягким, а именно scope и life cycle. Сначала указано начало области видимости, а вместо указания ее окончания разговор переходит на жизненный цикл.

Comment: @vitaliy4us в описании жизненного цикла scope тоже применяется, но в своем контексте разумеется, наиболее близким будет - область действия, или время жизни. Я обычно использую последний вариант. Ну и да. оригинал тоже пишут люди, а правильно донести свои мысли и знания до других людей - задача не менее сложная, чем получить эти знания.